# Generalized minimum chi-square estimators?

Tags: chi-squared-test, gamma-distribution, estimators, extreme-value

I need to implement the generalized minimum chi-square estimators (alternative to L-moments method and maximum likelihood estimate (MLE)) for estimate the parameters of the gamma distribution. 
My first question is: for the generalized minimum chi-square estimators method, what is the correct bibliography (paper, book, etc.) to cite?
and
does anyone know of any package in R (or other software) where this method is implemented?

Thank you all

Comment: Minimum chi-square for estimation is quite old; Neyman and Pearson discuss some of its properties in 1928, but it was being used long before - before estimation by maximum likelihood, for example. You may find 
Harris and Kanji (1983) "On the Use of Minimum Chi-Square Estimation," *Journal of the Royal Statistical Society. Series D (The Statistician)* Vol. 32, No. 4 (Dec.), pp. 379-394 of some help in locating additional references.

Answer (score 2):

There is a nice paper by Joseph Berkson, "Minimum chi-square, not maximum likelihood!", *The Annals of Statistics* 1980; 8(3): 457-487. In R there are several packages for least-squares estimation; for minimum chi-square estimation, `mipfp` may be worth a look.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @al cliver. At present, this is more of a comment than an answer by our standards. Can you expand on it? Eg, can you give a summary of what is in the paper so future readers can decide if it's something they want to pursue? How would the information in the paper resolve the OP's issue?

Comment: @Sven It seems to me this is a good answer--it's the question that's marginal, because it's only asking for references and software.  Welcome to our site, Al, and thank you for your contribution!

Comment: @whuber Agreed.

Comment: The Berkson paper is available at [project euclid](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1176345003). The paper was submitted in 1977 but not published until 1980; even allowing for the longer time for the discussants to respond, that must have been an arduous review process.